# Big Query - Will I be get charged for the tables(having only project read access role) that are shared with others?

Tags: google-bigquery

(Assume I have 100 tables, I have shared the tables with more than 1000 students and I have set the project to  project read access role.) When these students access all the tables in my project using select clause, wil I be get charged?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will be charged for storage only - https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing#storage - and each student will be charged in their respective billing projects - https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing#queries

Comment: If I have active storage table of 1GB and long-term storage table of 1GB, Will I be get charged each month?

Comment: No, because the first 10GB of storage each month is free.

Comment: If I use INSERT DML statement for inserting the rows into the table in Web UI, Wll I be get charged? Likewise for UPDATE statement?